# How to fire a web service call every 2 minutes

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to implement a service that will go fetch Stock details every 2 minutes. Stock details are more prone to change therefore, I have decided to fetch it every 2 minutes. I have implemented fetching the Stock details for just one instance, but how do I change my code so that it fires a request every 2 minutes during the first 12 hours of the day.

In brief :

1. I need to fetch Stock details every 2 minutes.
2. I only need to fire a request from 10AM to 3PM.

   ```
   this.myService.getDetailsStock(1).subscribe(
    (response) =>
    {
      this.allStockDetails= response.details;

    },
    (error) => 
    {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
   );
   ```

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: setInterval is not idiomatic in Angular. Using RxJS interval as described by the answer by Ritesh Waghela is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RxJS interval operator for this purpose: Link https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval

```
  import { interval } from 'rxjs';
    
  const apiIntervalSubscription = interval(2 * 60 * 1000)
     .pipe(mergeMap(() => this.myService.getDetailsStock(1)))
     .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

To stop firing the API after a specific time, we can create another interval where we can check the time every minute and when we reach a particular time, we can unsubscribe the
apiIntervalSubscription after that time, like this:

```
apiIntervalSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Given that the OP wants every x seconds switchMap is likely a better choice

Comment: `Observable.interval` has been deprecated for some time. it should be `import { interval } from 'rxjs';` now

Comment: @Liam Angular/RxJS version is not specified in OP. Still I have updated the answer considering the latest version.

Comment: switchMap is good when cancelling is required, here OP wants the API call in every 2 seconds, hence interval with mergeMap will serve the purpose.

Comment: this code make a call after 2 minutes, how can we make an inital call and then every 2 minutes ?

Comment: What if the initial call returns an error response, would you still like to make call after every 2 minute?